# Docker and XDebug not reading breakpoints VSCode

Tags: php, debugging, docker, xdebug

I have been using XDebug with PHP Version 7.0.* for the last 6 months on a MAC using remote debugging to a Docker container.

I was running an older version of docker that was using VirtualBox to VM for docker, all was working fine.

I recently updated docker to version 17.03.1 and have had nothing but issues with xDebug. I have contacted the creator of vscode-php-debug via an issue on his repository and he then pointed me to take the issue up with xdebug and or docker.

My issue is the following:

XDebug is running and working on my container, the xdebug log shows that it connects to my IDE but it simply closes the connection as if there are no breakpoints when I have breakpoints set in VSCode.

The issue I posted on vscode-php-debug can be found [here](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/158)

Which has a copy of my xDebug logs and VSCode debug logs... It shows that the connection is made but no breakpoints are hit.

I have read around a few blogs that docker now needs a loopback ip created for the connection to xdebug to work, which I have also tried and failed.

I'm finding it surprisingly hard to debug without a debugger after using one for so long.

I have tried many configs, reinstalled, rebooted, rebuilt images/containers and even have tried the docker and xdebug irc channels on freenode without any success.

Comment: Any chance you are on a Mac? Because there are quite some issues with docker for mac (community version) and xdebug. I got it working by executing a command every reboot.

Comment: Yes i am on a mac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT-2 2018**

The `remote_host` value can now be changed to support all platforms:

```
xdebug.remote_host = "host.docker.internal"
```

**EDIT-1 2018**
It's no longer needed to use the plist fix. As pointed out in this gist: https://gist.github.com/chadrien/c90927ec2d160ffea9c4#gistcomment-2398281 you can now use the docker for mac internal IP.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_host = "docker.for.mac.host.internal"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

---

**OLD CONFIG**

Since you are using docker on a mac I'm posting the way my solution worked. Most of the credits go to [this post on the docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/ip-address-for-xdebug/10460/31).

Assuming your installation of xdebug is correctly, this is my config in the `php.ini`.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_host=10.254.254.254
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
```

You can test your config by executing this command in your terminal. `sudo ifconfig en0 alias 10.254.254.254 255.255.255.0`.

If this is working you can convert it into a `plist` file and place it in the following location. `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.xdebugFix.plist`. Below you will find my version of the plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.docker.xdebugFix</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>ifconfig</string>
        <string>en0</string>
        <string>alias</string>
        <string>10.254.254.254</string>
        <string>255.255.255.0</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: The plist will only work after a reboot of your Mac.

---

**PHPSTORM Config (also needed after the 2018 edit)**

After that I set up my PHP storm with a debug server like this:
[image: php storm config 1]

[image: php storm config 2]

After that my breakpoints where working, if you're using chrome you'll also need to use the xdebug extension but I'm pretty sure you know this since you used it in the past.

Comment: This is the process i have already tried... with no succuess... but i might give it one more try today again

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working... I have tried with chrome's xdebug also... XDebug reports the connection as connected but no breakpoints and it doesn't even break on start if I set that in my IDE or chromes xdebug extension....

Comment: I found the issue and it was due to my docker-compose.yml setup... with the older version of docker that was running on VirtualBox I had to open my containers port 9000 up so that xDebug could use the tunnel to connect to my host... which with docker now causes conflicts...

So the above answer is correct but a side note to anyone that DID have port 9000 open on their container... it no longer needs to be open/forwarded

Comment: @joshualawson Cool! Feel free to edit the answer and add the docker-compose.yml info. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: xdebug.idekey="VSCODE" worked also fine for me

Comment: In VSCode you need to change the setting remote.localPortHost to allInterfaces as stated in https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/discussions/223

Answer (score 0):

Check your docker-compose.yml

I had an environment variable in mine:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${LAN_IP}
```

that needed to be changed to:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=${LAN_IP}
```

where LAN_IP is defined as your local LAN IP in your .env file

Answer (score 0):

I am working with `VSCODE devcontainer` and I use the config below:

My launch.json for VSCODE

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

I use `Dockerfile` with a RUN below to install xdebug:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

I find my xdebug config file in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`

I edit the file as below:

```
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

Or you can add it in Dockfile like below:

```
RUN echo ' \n[xdebug] \n\
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal  \n\
xdebug.mode=debug  \n\
xdebug.start_with_request=yes \n\
xdebug.idekey="VSCODE"  \n\
\n' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

`mode` This setting controls which Xdebug features are enabled. We’ve set `develop` to enable development aids, such as getting better error messages, and `debug` to enable step debugging.

`client_host` This setting tells Xdebug the IP address or hostname of the machine that is running your text editor or IDE.

`start_with_request` This setting determines whether a function trace, garbage collection statistics, profiling, or step debugging are activated at the start of a PHP request. Setting it to yes instructs Xdebug to always initiate a debugging session.

Ref. https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/