# docker-compose for Prestashop for Prestashop

Tags: docker, prestashop-1.7

[image]

i install the prestashop through docker

first step copy the prestashop files into the  www folder

when I run the 1'docker-compose up'  always display this error

help me bro

what is wrong in that

my system is win10  wsl
node 18

them is not match with php 7.4???

Comment: Try to follow the documentation here may be: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/environments/docker/

This should help.
Can you also add your docker compose file here?

Comment: I just want to do local code development from a remote server

Comment: I have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394844/5864034